# PHP: how to create an array with one _GET value and another one that is set

Tags: php, arrays, youtube

I am working on a call to the Youtube API. In this code the number of listings to return (maxResults) is set by the user through a form along with the search query. I want to set the maxResults myself and take away that choice from the user. In this piece of code, how can I set the maxResults to "30" instead of the $_GET['maxResults']?

```
 $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
'q' => $_GET['q'],
'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
));
```

Thanks!

Comment: how about replacing `$_GET['maxResults']` with `30`..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheers, try  this codes my friend. And remember, always use "[isset()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.isset.php)" validation on [super globals](http://php.net/manual/de/language.variables.superglobals.php).

```
 $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id, snippet', array(
     'q' => isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : null,
     'maxResults' => 30, //insert maxResult count here
));
```

Comment: Set doesn't mean not empty.

Comment: He said he wants to NOT use the parameter from the user. This code just adds a default value.

Comment: Thanks lin - 'maxResults' => 30 works. I had an IF statement further up that checked if the parameter was set from user, preventing the this bit from executing in the first place - duh. Your isset comment helped me realize this. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
 'q' => $_GET['q'],
 'maxResults' => 30,
 ));
```